# How to change dependency version of spring cloud gcp

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gcp

For spring boot i can see all the dependency properties names in the docs: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml so i can easily change them from gradle

but where can i find the same listing of dependencies for spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub

i wan't to change the version of `com.google.cloud:google-cloud-pubsub`

Comment: I don't think it's here, but the Google cloud bom is here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/master/spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies/pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/blob/master/spring-cloud-dependencies/pom.xml) are all the dependencies with their versions for `spring-cloud` listed.
For `spring-cloud-gcp` as [@spencergibb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2730527/spencergibb) said in his comment, all what I can find is [this](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/master/spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies/pom.xml)